# Text tokenizer - extract words and positions from text

Tags: java, string, tokenize, split

I have `Set` of `character` delimiters (`DELIMITERS`), eg `.` `,`  etc. Using this I want to split text and get words with their position in text. 
`String.split()` works fine if you want only words. The same with `StringTokenizer`. Wrote some simple method to deal with this, but maybe there is a better way to achieve this result?

```
public List<String> extractWords(String text){
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    List<WordPos> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    int wordStart = -1;
    for(int i=0; i < text.length(); i++){
        if(DELIMITERS.contains(text.charAt(i))){
            if(wordStart >=0){ //word just ended
                String word = text.substring(wordStart, i);
                positions.add(new WordPos(wordStart, i));
                words.add(word);
            }
            wordStart = -1;
        }else{ //not delimiter == valid word
            if(wordStart < 0){ //word just started
                wordStart = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}

// inner static class for words positions
public static class WordPos{
    int start;
    int end;
    public WordPos(int start, int end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

From efficiency perspective, I think your solution is not bad.
From aesthetic aspect (how the code looks), I would use [Apache Commons nStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) doing something like (haven't tried it):

1. spit all tokens using:
   [splitPreserveAllTokens()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#splitPreserveAllTokens(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int))
2. iterate over resulting array and store the token and the position of each that I would obtain from a call to lastIndexOf.

Comment: @silvaran, didn't you read the 1st sentence of of my answer? I was not saying that performance wise it is the best thing to do.... however, performance was not explicitly mentioned as an objective. I think from the point of view of 'clean code' it is better to have it both slim and readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
List<WordPos> positions = new ArrayList<>();
int index = 0;
String word = "";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("., ");


while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {

word = st.nextToken();
words.add(word);
positions.add(new WordPos(index,index+word.length()));

index+= word.length() +1;
}
```

With the above approach I suppose there aren't 2 consecutive delimiters. If this happens the approach is quite the same.

Comment: But there might be two delimiters. "John went home. The sky is blue." Dot and space together.

Comment: @bartektartanus Is there a fixed set of delimiters or could it change?